# Just a calculation

Tags: numerical-methods

Every day I have a problem while having simple calculations.

Can anyone give a Tip how to overcome? For Example :

How one will calculate the remainder of  $ 2^{546}\pmod{43} $ ? Without a calculator ??

And how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints applying modular arithmetic and Fermat's Little Theorem:

$$546=43\cdot 12+30\implies 2^{546}=2^{42}=1\pmod{43}$$

Comment: how would you manage $2^{30}\pmod{43}?$

Comment: $$2^7=128=-1\pmod{43}\implies 2^{30}=(2^7)^4\cdot 2^2=4\pmod{43}$$

Comment: that could safely be starting point like DepeHb's answer:)

Comment: I guess it could be, but I chose another approach. Is there something in my answer unclear to you, @labbhattacharjee ?

Answer (score 3):

43 and 2 are coprimes .

Euler number of 43 is 42 .

546 is multiple of 42 .

so remainder is 1  (fermat's theorem ). So no calculator used , yet solved just by observing numbers .

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $2^7 = 128$ and also $3\cdot 43 = 129$, so $2^7 = -1 \mod 43$. Now $546 = 7 \cdot 78$, so $2^{546} = (2^{7})^{78} = (-1)^{78} \mod 43 = 1 \mod 43$.